# Adding files to bluemix volume

Tags: docker, command-line, ibm-cloud, docker-volume, ibm-cloud-tools

I am new to docker and bluemix and trying to deploy my application on bluemix. I want to add application config file in volume so that all the containers can read the same config file.

I followed all the steps given by bluemix here - 
https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/containers/container_volumes_mount.html

These are the commands I executed -

```
cf ic volume create myvolume
OK
The volume 'myvolume' was created.
cf ic volume list
myVolume
cf ic run --volume myvolume:/usr/xyz--name singleVolContainer registry.portal.bluemix.net/my_services/dockerexample:1.0
8aad1ab7-42c3-2344-890b-0a345eb6d74c
cf ic cp ./config.properties 8aad1ab7-42c:/usr/xyz
cf ic exec -it 8aad1ab7-42c bash
 cd /usr/xyz
bash: cd: /usr/xyz: Not a directory
```

Now instead of copying file to xyz directory, it has copied the content of the file to a new file named "xyz".

What am I doing wrong?

How do I copy the file to volume and how can I check that container is able to read the file in volume?

**Added -**

I run df command after running the instance and gave me following output (there is no volume mounted)-

```
Filesystem                                                                                         1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/docker-252:0-28311560-283985acbf138a13244821e88ff85f7b04b80938076a02c4d64cb1efa9923986  10190136    399364   9250100   5% /
tmpfs                                                                                               14409504         0  14409504   0% /dev
tmpfs                                                                                               14409504         0  14409504   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mapper/kraken--host--01--vg-root                                                              744810064 111867496 595085288  16% /etc/hosts
shm                                                                                                    65536         0     65536   0% /dev/shm
udev                                                                                                14398352        12  14398340   1% /dev/tty
```

**Added more -**

I think I have found the problem -

```
cf ic volume create volnew
OK
The volume 'volnew' was created.

cf ic volume fs-inspect volnew
FAILED

{
    "code": "IC5000E",
    "description": "An issue occurred in IBM Containers. Contact Bluemix Support and reference this incident ID.",
    "incident_id": "some_id",
    "name": "DefaultMessage",
    "rc": "500",
    "type": "General"
}
```

**More Information**

cf ic volume fs-list

```
Name                                   Size   IOPS/GB   Created               State
4c334ff9-a516-46c8-92df-c5cadbd7f6ff   0      0.00      2016-11-02 14:41:34   ERROR-('Connection aborted.', error(111, 'ECONNREFUSED'))
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM tomcat:8.0
MAINTAINER abc
ADD settings.xml /usr/local/tomcat/conf/
ADD tomcat-users.xml /usr/local/tomcat/conf/
ADD RESTfulExample.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/
```

Comment: The command looks good (although it should be a space between `myvolume:/usr/xyz` and `--name`, but I believe this is a typo). I just tested it and it worked fine. After creating the container can you check if the volume was actually mounted under `/usr/xyz` directory? You can run the `cf ic exec` command and then run `df` to check.

Comment: Checked using df command, space in not mounted (Added df output above). Space problem is just a typo.

Comment: can you try to mount the volume in one of the default images? If you are in US South region try this command `cf ic run --volume myvolume:/usr/xyz --name singleVolContainer registry.ng.bluemix.net/ibmliberty `. If you are in UK region then use `registry.eu-gb.bluemix.net/ibmliberty` image. And check if the volume was mounted. Trying to see if the problem is your account or your image.

Comment: Hi Alex..Thanks for your time..There seems to be some problem with created volume (added more info above).. I have already forwarded the problem to IBM formally now..

Comment: I saw your last additions to the question, but the command to inspect the volume is not correct. You should run the following command: `cf ic volume inspect volnew` instead.

Comment: Oh..I was doubting it too.. But did not find any documentation about "fs-" command so I tried it... Added some more information after running command "cf ic volume fs-list". Is this information any good for us? Anyways, now that you tell me that the command is not correct, I will try to mount the volume in one of the default images as you suggested tomorrow morning...

Comment: If you can post your dockerfile I can check if there is anything suspicious as well.

Comment: I have nothing related to volume in my dockerfile.. but I am adding it anyway so that you can check.. Thanks..

Comment: Per the Bluemix  status page (ibm.bix/bluemixstatus) there was a problem with volumes in past days. Could you please try again and see if it is working now?

Comment: Hi Alex.. I tried again but it still doesn't work.. I tried to mount the volume on default ibmliberty image.. but when I do "cf ic exec -t <identifier>", and try to go into /usr/xyz directory, it is not there...

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know how to help anymore. Please work with Bluemix support via a formal ticket (I believe you already opened per one of your comments above).

Comment: Yeah.. Thanks anyways for the help..